# getting "Input string was not in a correct format" upon starting QuickFixN

Tags: c#, quickfix

I have a C# application that has used QuickFixN successfully for some time now.

This morning after a machine crash, when I restart I get "Input string was not in correct format" here:

```
    System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Convert.ToInt32(String value)
   at QuickFix.FileStore.ConstructFromFileCache()
   at QuickFix.FileStore.open()
   at QuickFix.FileStore..ctor(String path, SessionID sessionID)
   at QuickFix.FileStoreFactory.Create(SessionID sessionID)
   at QuickFix.Session..ctor(IApplication app, IMessageStoreFactory storeFactory, SessionID sessID, DataDictionaryProvider dataDictProvider, SessionSchedule sessionSchedule, Int32 heartBtInt, ILogFactory logFactory, IMessageFactory msgFactory, String senderDefaultApplVerID)
   at QuickFix.SessionFactory.Create(SessionID sessionID, Dictionary settings)
   at QuickFix.AbstractInitiator..ctor(IApplication app, IMessageStoreFactory storeFactory, SessionSettings settings, ILogFactory logFactory, IMessageFactory messageFactory)
   at QuickFix.Transport.SocketInitiator..ctor(IApplication application, IMessageStoreFactory storeFactory, SessionSettings settings, ILogFactory logFactory)
```

How do I rectify?

Comment: Start by posting the code that its crashing on as well as the input values.

Comment: that's within QuickFix, I don't know what the input values are

Comment: As this site is for programming, I'm not sure how we'll be able to help you.  Perhaps this would do better over at [su]

Comment: FWIW, this is a c# error that happens when you try to parse a string into a number and the string is not a number.

Comment: thanks, understood. Just solved it so I posted an answer anyhow.

Comment: You should be aware that if this gets any attention, its likely to be closed as off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting all the QuickFix store rectified the problem.

Obviously this is a little dangerous - messages can be lost.

Comment: **Incorrect**.  You deleted the **store** (which is referenced in the stacktrace).  The store and the log are totally different things, though fools sometimes configure them to go in the same dir.

Comment: You are right, I have deleted the store, and that has solve the problem. I don't think I have logging enabled

Answer (score 0):

Hope you backed up the store? If you sort the store by timestamp you can find the message that caused the problem...

Comment: I have, but obviously the store has multiple files - which one should I be looking in?

Comment: You can get some info from the body file, but I am not sure that it records exceptions. Whats the filelogpath in your cfg file? Navigate there and look into the messages.current.log